# Comparing Doctor Who footage before/after 2005 by total airtime

Tags: doctor-who

In terms of minutes of total airtime, is there now more Doctor Who since the 2005 revival, compared to episodes (and films) made before 2005?

Comment: These numbers would be easy to approximate, but nearly impossible to get truly accurately. Also, there are a lot of edge cases; do you include the 1960s *Dr. Who* films? *The Scream of the Shalka*? *Torchwood*? The original *Shada* never aired, but was later released at least twice on video, DVD, webisode, and audio dramas of varying length. Modern webisodes, mini-episode intros, *Red Nose Day* productions? *The Curse of Fatal Death*? What about "Previously on" recaps? Both old and new Who make use of them, and in Old Who it was often gratuitous when they needed to pad the episodes...

Comment: I'd like to include films - I suspect spin-offs don't count....

Comment: If spin-offs don't count for you, I'm not sure you'd consider the *Dr. Who* films to count either; I'm not using "Dr." as shorthand, look them up. My point is that "airtime" is hard to define: simply counting the episode minutes will get you a lot of duplicate footage, and will ignore a *wealth* of footage that is definitely *Doctor Who* but not necessarily episodes or canon, while saying things like "all films" will get you hours of definitively *non*-canon footage. This franchise is... messy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, not even close. By my calculation (using the [list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_serials)) there were 695 episodes of the original incarnation, all but 13 of which were 25 minutes long (those 13 were 45 minutes long). This makes 17050+585=17,635 minutes of original.

By contrast, the new series has 102 episodes of between 45-70 minutes, which makes about (I can't be bothered to work it out exactly) 5,000 minutes: less than a third as much.

Comment: Beat me to it - using the same list I had an approximation of 347½ hours vs 103¾ hours.

Comment: There isn't a way to calculate *original* airtime, is there? That is, ignoring the repeat footage from the (often several minutes long) "previously on" recaps?

Comment: @BESW I don't see how you could do it other than re-watching every episode armed with a sonic stopwatch...

Comment: Wibbly Wobbly Timey Wimey...Stuff :-)

Comment: @PhilPursglove: two months have gone by, and no-one’s done this yet!? I know some old episodes are still lost, but *come on people*. Work for those rep points!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite ;-)